# How to remove plastic retainer sleeve stuck in faucet handle threading?

Tags: shower, faucet, stuck

I have a plastic "retainer sleeve" that threaded into my shower faucet handle a bit off and is now stuck. Any advice on getting this piece off?

[image]

Comment: With or without destroying the plastic?

Comment: Either way will work for me!

Answer (score 2):

Your shower faucet handle appears to be made of metal.  Heat the metal by soaking it in hot water for a while.  Then try unscrewing the sleeve.  The heated metal should expand making the threads looser.

Be careful to avoid buring yourself with hot metal.

Comment: You can also stick some ice cubes inside the plastic to shrink the plastic a little.  When the plastic is good and cold, put the whole thing in hot water to expand the metal, or use a heat gun or hair dryer on a low setting on the metal.

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck in the past using a flat head screw driver or an awl to remove stuck pieces of threaded plastic. It will damage if not ruin the plastic piece, but if you drive the point in a bit and then angle the piece, you can slowly cause it to unscrew enough to get a pair of vise grips to finish it.